# Know when animation is done when animation is abstracted out iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

Having a bit of an issue, searched some similar questions but couldn't get things going. I have a simple button animation that I use across my project in a utilities class I made. The problem is that the buttons code executes before the animation is done.

Code for animation in utilities class.m:

```
+(void)buttonBobble:(UIButton *)button{
  button.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.8, 0.8);
  [UIView beginAnimations:@"button" context:nil];
  [UIView setAnimationDuration:.5];
  button.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1);
  [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

What I have tried to make sure the animation is done before code fires in any button:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.0f delay:0.0f options: UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone  animations:^{
    [Utilities buttonBobble:sender];
}completion:^(BOOL finished){
    //Do stuff
}];
```

*Even if that worked*, I wish to abstract it out to where I could do something like this:

```
if([Utilities buttonBobble:sender]){
  //Make it send a BOOL so when it's done I execute stuff like normal
}
```

Any ideas welcome.

Comment: You want the animation to be synchronous, or you just want callback solution like Josh answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your utility method to take a completion block that encapsulates the actions you need that button to take when it's done bobbling:

```
+(void)buttonBobble:(UIButton *)button 
     actionWhenDone:(void (^)(BOOL))action
{
    button.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.8, 0.8);
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
        button.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1);
     }
                     completion:action];
}
```

In the original button action method, then, you pass along that action block rather than running the code directly in the method:

```
- (IBAction)buttonAction:(id)sender
{
    [Utilities buttonBobble:sender
             actionWhenDone:^(BOOL finished){
                // Your code here
        }];
    // Nothing here.
}
```

As a design note, you might also consider putting that utility method into a category on `UIButton`:

```
@implementation UIButton (JMMBobble)

- (void)JMMBobbleWithActionWhenDone:(void (^)(BOOL))action
{
    self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.8, 0.8);
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
        self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1);
     }
                     completion:action];
}
```

Then the action looks like

```
- (IBAction)buttonAction:(id)sender
{
    [sender JMMBobbleWithActionWhenDone:^(BOOL finished){
                // Your code here
        }];
}
```

Comment: Good thought on the category, I will probably move it there. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I like to do it differently, especially if animations will be nested after each other I find my code easier to write / read if I split it up using `NSTimers`. You can see that the timers are using the same interval as the animation time.

```
-(void)fadeOutText{
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"fadeOutText" context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    someButton.titleLabel.alpha = 0.0f;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(changeTextAndFadeIn)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:NO];
}
-(void)changeTextAndFadeIn{
    [someButton setTitle:@"Testing" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"fadeInText" context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    someButton.titleLabel.alpha = 1.0f;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(finishedFading)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:NO];
}
-(void)changeTextAndFadeIn{
    //Code to be executed after text has faded out / changed / faded in.
}
```

Comment: It should perhaps be noted that there's no guarantee that the timers will actually fire at exactly the time that the animations finish. In practice, it's likely to be such small difference as to be unnoticeable, but it's certainly possible for a timer to be delayed if its run loop is busy.